# How do I dereference a pointer in Go?

Tags: pointers, go

In the Go language, is there any way to convert `*string` to `string`? (or, for that matter, any  `*T` to `T`?)

I have looked on the internet and through some Go documentation, but I can't find it - may have missed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To turn a `*T` into a `T`, use the `*` operator:

```
func Dereference(strptr *string) string {
    return *strptr
}
```

I highly suggest you to read about *pointers* before proceeding with the language. They are a fundamental concept without which it is impossible to use the language efficiently.

Comment: @acsiola, note that, of course, there's no need to write a function to dereference pointers -- it was provided solely for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: @kostix, Yes, I noticed. Thank you! :)